# make for loop faster in R without parallalizing

Tags: r, loops, optimization

I have the following very simple loop operation where I need to loop from 1 to 50,000. Although the loop is very simple, itàs very slow in R, so I'm wondering if there is any operation can do to make it faster, but I don't prefer parallel solution since my computer has only 2 processors,

```
full3 = fullData
for(i in 1:dim(fullData)[1]) {
  full3[i,923] <- sum(as.numeric(full3[i, 879:912]))
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: What are you calling "very slow" ? Also avoiding to call print at each iteration should give you much better performance.

Comment: (+1) @SachaPercot-Tétu for mentioning to avoid print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the vectorised `rowSums` operation for this:

```
full3 <- fullData
# a[, b] selects the entire column 'b' from data.frame 'a'
full3[, 923] <- rowSums(as.numeric(full3[, 879:912]))
```

should do it. `rowSums`, well, calculates the sum of each row of the subset'd `data.frame` `full3[, 879:912]`. This result is stored back in column 923